# cancel previous same request in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, fetch

I do use fetch request for GET and POST data. With an help of that, I did make a one input box where on every change of that input I do call API for find relative data. But it's call on every change so sometimes it's print the previous request's data instead of recent request's data.

So, for that, I want to cancel that previous request on new same request call. is there any way to make that possible.

Note: I did use AbortController though it gives me functionality to cancel the current request only.

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: Actually i do have problem on that how can i write the code for preventing same previous requests.

Comment: @RajnishKatharotiya Are you using redux-saga ?